# UIButton is not receiving actions behind UIScrollView

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview, uibutton, uiresponder, touch-up-inside

I put `UIButton` inside `UITableViewCell` in `UITableView` that is behind `UIScrollView`. I subclassed `UIScrollView` to forward touches to `UITableView`.

So method from `UITableViewDelegate didSelectRow` is calling properly. The problem is that `UIButton` inside table cell is not receiving `TouchUpInside` actions.

How can I solve this problem without deleting `ScrollView` over `TableView`?

EDIT:

I resolved this issue by detecting which view will receive touch. Here's the code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *hitView = [self hitTest:[(UITouch*)[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self] withEvent:event];
    if ([hitView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [(UIButton*)hitView sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Would like to share your method for capturing didSelect tableView delegate's method for a tableview behind a scrollview ? Thx a lot !

Comment: There's nothing special in method -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. Calling of his method is OK even when tableView is behind scrollView.

Comment: Weird because I can scroll my UIScrollView but can't call -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I forgot... I overided methods touchesBegan: touchesEnded: touchesMoved: touchesCancelled: in my scrollView and I'm sending touches to tableView behind. It looks like this: - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.behindTable touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to enable actions for bouth objects - UIScrollView and UIButton you should to implement custom hit test mechanism for ScrollView.

In your UIScrollView subclass override - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event method to make views behind ScrollView available for getting events.

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return __touchesEnabled;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    _touchesEnabled = NO;
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
    for(UITouch *touch in touches) {
       CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
       point = [window convertPoint:point fromView:self];
       UIView *view = [window hitTest:point withEvent:event];
       [view touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }  
    _touchesEnabled = YES;
}
```

It works for me

Comment: If I do this the buttons receive the event but now the views inside the scrollview don't, and I can't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added your scroll view over the UIButton, all the touch actions will not be passed to the button.

```
    [yourScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

This may solve your problem.

Comment: this would not work for me, because my scrollView have to be able to capture events and scroll